# Is this correct usage of super in python?

Tags: python, django

```
class SessionWizardView(WizardView):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        #...snipped..
        pass

class ParentWizard(SessionWizardView):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SessionWizardView, cls).as_view( ... )

class ChildWizard(ParentWizard):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(SessionWizardView, cls).as_view( ... )
```

In `ChildWizard`, is it legal to pass in a grandparent class (`SessionWizardView`) into the first parameter of `super` ? pylint is vomiting this error message:

> Method should have "self" as first argument
>
> Bad first argument 'SessionWizardView' given to super class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual usage of super for classmethods is to put *cls* first and the name of the current class as the second argument:

```
class SessionWizardView(WizardView):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        #...snipped..
        pass

class ParentWizard(SessionWizardView):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(cls, ParentWizard).as_view( ... )

class ChildWizard(ParentWizard):
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(cls, ChildWizard).as_view( ... )
```

If you build working code that passes tests, I wouldn't worry to much about how *pylint* reports the naming of the first argument.  *pylint* knows that a standard Python *classmethod* will use *cls* as the first argument, but it doesn't know anything about *classonlymethod* which has the same pattern.

References:

- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super
- http://blogs.gnome.org/jamesh/2005/06/23/overriding-class-methods-in-python/
- http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:c0202